# HTTPS IP changes to Localhost

Tags: rhel, http, https

I install iTOP and applied SSL on httpd . When i try to access from same machine everything works perfectly as shown in below image .

[image]

Now when i try to access the test-vm from any other subnet the icons doesn't appear and url changes from 172.18.35.8 to localhost and gives error

[image]

[image]

## HTTPD.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 172.18.35.8
    Redirect permanent / https://172.18.35.8/
    #ErrorLog logs/test-itop-error_log
    #CustomLog logs/test-itop-access_log common
</VirtualHost>


NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    #ServerAdmin admin@test-itop
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/itop
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName test-itop.local
    ErrorLog logs/test-itop-error_log
    CustomLog logs/test-itop-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

## Hosts File

```
127.0.0.1               test-itop localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6               

172.18.35.8     test-itop.local         test-itop
```

What im missing here ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the application level, and not configuration of your hosts files or apache probably.

I would advise to take out test-itop of that line of 127.0.0.1; however I do suspect the problem is not there.

The most likely explanation is that in the web interface of the setup phase, in "Miscellaneous Parameters"->"Additional Parameters"->"Application URL" you put http://localhost/itop instead of https://172.18.35.8/itop ; and this also explains why it works well when being used from the localhost.

As a final recommendation, from the performance point of view, I would recommend not setting up application servers with graphical interfaces; or at most installing them, but only launching the xserver when needed, keeping it not running the majority of the time.

Disclaimer: never dealt with iTop, but have seen this problem in other web applications. I got the screen/configuration detail from [here](https://www.unixmen.com/setup-operational-portal-using-itop-centosdebian/)

Comment: absolutely right, i forgot the add my answer. The issue was at application level . I added the ip in config-itop.php "'app_root_url' => 'http://172.18.35.8/itop/' " and it solved the problem . Thank you and good day to you

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a wrong parameter in the config files.

Even if you would do a prototype you should add all ready-to-release  correct info, at your case I would do that and modify /etc/hosts to re-point the domain to the correct test environment (i.e localhost or a private range).
That's another reason to always consider DNS over static ip's.